# rake db:migrate does nothing in Rails 4.1 app and exits without errors

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rails-migrations, dbmigrate

I'm setting up a brand-new Rails 4.1 app and using 64-bit PostgreSQL 9.3.4 as my development server. Everything goes smoothly until I run `rake db:migrate`. Nothing happens. I ran the command again with the `--trace` flag, and it looks like the app is not processing my migrations and finishes without error:

```
rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

The migrations are basic stuff like a `User` table. Some are auto-generated by the Comfortable Mexican Sofa gem, and some are my own extracted from another Rails 4 app.

When I run `rake db:migrate:status` it shows all of my migrations as down/pending:

```
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
  down    20120117051823  Create sessions table
  down    20120117051824  Create users
  down    20120117051910  Create categories
  down    20120117051947  Create statuses
  down    20120117052044  Create settings
  down    20120117052336  Create roles
  down    20120117053039  Create emails
  down    20120117053111  Create urls
  down    20120117053152  Create pictures
  down    20120117053441  Create addresses
  down    20120117053516  Create phones
  down    20120117053716  Create notes
  down    20120117053849  Create announcements
  down    20120117054118  Create contacts
  down    20120117060145  Users have and belong to many roles
  down    20121018184843  Create translations
  down    20140407233039  Create cms
```

I can run `rake db:create` and `rake db:drop` without issue, which confirms that I have proper access rights to the PostgreSQL server.

I tried using SQLite in place of PostgreSQL, but I get the same issue: it creates `development.sqlite` and `test.sqlite` just fine, but doesn't populate them. I eliminated things like access rights, writable files/directories, etc. I even tried setting up a new PostgreSQL server and had the same issue. Also, my old Rails 3 and Rails 4 apps that are connecting to the same server run just fine.

I also tried setting up an app using RailsComposer in case my template was the problem, but I ran into the same issue.

According to some Stack Overflow answers other people have had the same issue when using Devise and CanCan, but I don't use either one: I use Authlogic as my authentication system and Pundit as my authorization system.

What might be causing this issue?

**UPDATE**

OK, my code works with both PostgreSQL and SQLite if I run it on 64-bit Windows 7 system using Ruby 1.9.3. But, it still doesn't work on my dev box running 64-bit Debian 7 with Ruby 2.1.1 or Ruby 2.0.0. (Note: I'm running rbenv.)

**UPDATE 2**

`rake db:schema:load` works on both Windows and my Debian machine. Only `rake db:migrate` is not working.

Comment: Do you have a stray RAILS_ENV setting perhaps?

Comment: @muistooshort - nope. I tried setting it up expclicitely in the command line - to no avail. Also I rebooted the system multiple times so if there was a rouge ENV stuck somewhere in memory it would be gone   -:)

Comment: Have you checked your `schema_migrations` table for anything strange? How about `schema.rb`? Just throwing out some wild guesses.

Comment: Another crazy idea: could there be some encoding weirdness somewhere? UTF-16 vs UTF-8 or something like that?

Comment: I appreciate your guesses :-) schema_migrations looks ok. When I run my migrations on my Windows 7 machine, they work fine, but not on my Debian 7 machine. Everything is UTF-8. I do this on purpose to avoide encoding nightmare.

Comment: Have you tried starting a brand new test app to see if the migrations work properly there? What happens if you manually `db:migrate:redo VERSION=...` the migrations? Does anything change? Could any of the binary chunks of your gems be out of date or be compiled for different versions of system libraries or anything like that?

Comment: Is the system clock correct on your Debian box?

Comment: Tried an empty app. Same issue.  I', running ntpd all machines, and they all sync to my firewall which acts as an ntp server. I 'll check that it's running

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure out what was going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question for posterity: I think the problem was with the virtual machine. I ended switching to a Debian 7.6 using vagrant and the problem went away.

Specifically I think it had to so how the underlying file system was mapped from linux guest to Windows host.